# Best cheap remote software to login to work with clients

Tags: remote-access, remote-control

I wanted recommendation please on software I can use to assist clients remotely, this could involve excel, access or other system issues. Could you please let me know the best way to go about this without having to pay capital costs, I don't have the budget, this process is all new to me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/) is a free remote control software package. With TightVNC, you can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it with your local mouse and keyboard, just like you would do it sitting in the front of that computer. TightVNC is:
>
> - free for both personal and commercial usage, with full source code available,
>   useful in administration, tech support, education, and for many other purposes,
> - cross-platform, available for Windows and Unix, with Java client included,
> - compatible with standard VNC software, conforming to RFB protocol specifications

It is great, simple, free and well documented/supported. I have been using it for decades and highly recommend it.

But, of course, your clients have to install it too (they as server, you as client)